# Here I wrote a java function for mean calculation

Tags: java

The function reads numbers from the user, summing them up in the process until the user enters the string "end". It then stops input & displays the avg of the numbers.

```
void mean() {
int mean1,f1=0,c1=0,g1;
boolean k1;
String end=null;
System.out.println("Enter numbers");
while(k1=false)
{
    end=input.nextLine();
    if(isNumeric(end)==true)
    {
        g1=Integer.parseInt(end);
        f1=f1+g1;
        c1=c1+1;
    }
    else if(end=="end")
    {
        k1=true;
    }
}
mean1=f1/c1;
System.out.println("The mean is: "+mean1);
}
```

However I am unable to escape the loop no matter what, even when the user enters "end".

Comment: I rolled back the question. You edited a critical part (i.e. the `String`-comparison via `==`), rendering already existing answers invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're using the assignment operator inside the while condition
use `==` instead and initialize the k1 as false.

```
void mean() {
int mean1,f1=0,c1=0,g1;
boolean k1 = false;
String end=null;
System.out.println("Enter numbers");
while(k1==false)
{
    end=input.nextLine();
    if(isNumeric(end)==true)
    {
        g1=Integer.parseInt(end);
        f1=f1+g1;
        c1=c1+1;
    }
    else if(end.equals("end"))
    {
        k1=true;
    }
}
mean1=f1/c1;
System.out.println("The mean is: "+mean1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `while` loop you are using `while(k1=false)`, which is an assignment operator. To compare values you need to use `==`. The `while(k1=false)` would set `k1` to `false` for each iteration. Since initialization statement returns the initialized variable itself, such a condition would always return `true`. This would make the statement `k1=true` inside the `else if` to be useless.

Also, string comparisons should be done using the `equals` method.

Since the `k1` variable is `boolean`, it is enough to use `while(!k1)` instead of using `while(k1 == false)`.

Also, please note that it is always better to give meaningful names to variables.
I would suggest you to rename the variable `k1` to something more meaningful like `hasMoreInput`.

Also, rather than initializing it to `false`, initialize it to `true` and change it to `false` whenever there are no more inputs from the user.

```java
boolean hasMoreInput = true;
while (hasMoreInput) { // more readable than while (!k1)
    // rest of the code.
    else if(end.equals("end")) {
        hasMoreInput = false;
    }    
}
```